# Build Mini Linux and Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, compiling, initrd

**How to build Mini Linux with Busybox, Kernel-3.15.3, Syslinux?**

[image: Boot Mini Linux Test with Qemu]

I've built my Mini Linux using these steps:

> > Steps in Building Base Mini Linux Distro
> >     
> >     0 . Compile the kernel and see the result in terms of size of the compilation ;
> >     
> >     1. Create rootfs image ( format as ext2 mke2fs for example ) that will contain the root system and some basic programs (used busybox ) ;
> >     
> >     2 . Mount rootfs and create basic directories and files ;
> >     
> >     3 . Compile busybox and install it inside the rootfs ;
> >     
> >     4 . Check the kernel size ( with or without modules enabled ) and Ciar image (with mkdosfs applied to the image ' linux.img ' example) that contain linux.img grub or syslinux setting the boot process of the system;
> >     
> >     5 . After rootfs created and linux , copy for syslinux.cfg linux.img , bzImage , into the linux.img. I use #find ./ cpio --create --format='newc'>initrd (to create "initrd" of rootfs) and copy it to linux.img;
> >     
> >     6 . Applies the command ' sync' syslinux to finish the linux.img image ;
> >     
> >     7 . After all settings and installations test it with qemu , for example, the following command qemu linux.img ' ;
> >     
> >     8 . If everything ok the system will boot and will fall in the basic shell .
> >     But the current attempts can not enter the terminal ( shell ) ;
> >     I leave here resgistred steps if it can help someone or someone can help me .

However, I have failed to execute `init`, as shown in the figure.

In other tests, I've obtained other problems of panic kernel, as root is not found.

I used this reference:

http://www.slideshare.net/sherif_mosa/003-embedded-linuxminiosx86

[http://free­electrons.com/](http://free%C2%ADelectrons.com/) Tutorial "Embbeded Linux From Scratch"

Comment: I find error. It's in compile busybox. I build busybox compiled as "shared lib" but config the system to it shared and build again like "no shared library".
But my doubt will be how configure it in this case (with shared library).

Comment: Other question that I found was configure and create tty.